# Undo git add, commit and push WITHOUT losing untracked files

Tags: git, git-rebase, undo, git-reset, git-revert

I accidentally added, committed, and pushed all my untracked files to a remote repo where they would be annoying to my collaborators.

Since then, I also made another two commits, one of which was merging with the remote via git pull.

I want to undo this sequence of actions and restore my directory to its prior state (INCLUDING the untracked files).

With all the commands I've tried (checkout, revert, reset, rebase), my untracked files are lost as a result of undoing commits.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

```
1. git log
2. copy hash of the commit that you accidentally pushed
3. git revert HEAD
4. git push
5. git cherry-pick HASHFROMSTEPTWO
```

This will revert your changes and push that to your master so that other people no longer have to see your files. Step 5 will then bring back all the files and changes you had made in the original commit and add it ontop of the revert.

Comment: Only thing I would add: `git cherry-pick -n commitid` Because I think he does not want to do the same commit again

Comment: I have multiple commits, including a merge that I want to undo.  I guess git revert HEAD will only revert the last commit.  What should I do in my case?

Comment: @David - you can replace HEAD with the hash of the last commit you want to keep. so: ```git revert HASH```

Comment: The files are still tracked after I do this.  Is there a way to undo the add as well? There were many untracked files that I don't plan to commit any time soon, and it would take a lot of work to figure out which and manually git rm them.

Comment: @aashnisshah: I think that syntax is incorrect.  The default is to specify a list of commits to undo.  I think the correct syntax would be commitid..HEAD

Comment: So when I try this on the real deal, I get: error: could not apply 65ac6c1... latest changes
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'

Comment: After resolving conflicts, you need to add the files back into the commit by doing a 'git add' for each file that you had edited